# Android Java GetMethod NoSuchMethodException

Tags: java, android, exception, reflection, nosuchmethoderror

I'm getting this problem during designtime and can't for the life of me work out why.

As a test, I've put in a literal value "blah", however this will be a variable later:

```
public void InitNewFragment(int FragmentNumber) {
    //Initialisation code for specific fragment

    Method[] listofmethods = FragManager.class.getMethods();


    Method m = FragManager.class.getDeclaredMethod("blah");
    Method mm = FragManager.class.getMethod("blahblah", Integer.class);

    //m.invoke(null);
    //mm.invoke(null, 7);
}

public void blah() {

}
public void blahblah(int x) {

}
```

I'm using this code to get a method based on a selected value from another list, but here using the literal value of blah() and blahblah().

getMethods() works fine during debugging.

**getMethod** and **getDeclaredMethod** are causing errors **during Design Time**

Any ideas?

Many thanks,
J

Comment: the mouse-over error during design time is: "Unhandled Exception: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException"

Comment: If you have unhandled exception, why don't you use `try-catch` or `throws...`?

Comment: The compiler cannot verify that the invokation will work at run-time, hence it is forcing you to handle the exception that may result in your code.

Comment: Oh I see. It's just looking for a handler. Thanks